# Replacint part of string from a certain point

Tags: mysql, sql

i have found some wrong text in 120 record in a table so i have in a varchar field:
'Name rubbish rubbish2 more rubbish'
i want to keep 'Name' en remove all after Name
i have tried this :

```
SELECT  REPLACE(field_name, 'rubbish','') as test
from table
where field_name like '%rubbish%'
```

but this will ofcourse remove only 'rubbish' not the rest.
I think ther must be a way to remove everything after 5 digits!?
Txs

Comment: Please edit your question and provide actual examples of the strings and the problems in them.

Comment: if you only need 5CHAR, just change your table field format for varchar(5), it'll drop everything after... ; you can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html to make advanced search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove everything after the first space character:

```
update mytable set
field_name = substr(field_name, 1, instr(field_name, ' '))
where field_name like '%rubbish%';
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcff40/1).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, if you want to keep everything before the first space, then you can use `substring_index()`:

```
update t
    set col = substring_index(col, ' ', 1)
    where col like '% %';
```

If you have some set pattern, such as the string `'rubbish'`, then you can use that.  So, this keeps everything before "rubbish":

```
update t
    set col = substring_index(col, 'rubbish', 1)
    where col like '%rubbish%';
```

You can also use this logic in a `SELECT` statement:

```
select substring_index(col, 'rubbish', 1)
. . .
```

If the string does not contain "rubbish", then everything is returned.